# How to input command on new line after current path?

Tags: gnome-terminal

How to setup terminal in ubuntu 18.04 like the picture?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```bash
PS1='\e[92m╭[\e[96mkiwish-4.2\e[92m]-(\e[39mvue-series/kendoi-vue\e[92m)-\e[93m[22%] \n\e[39m╰>'
```